# Python Flask Rest Plus - Return Response object along with description

Tags: python, flask-restplus

I'm using Python Flask RestPlus framework, pretty new to Python. Trying to send back a response object along with some description and status code but failing with the following error:

```
TypeError: Object of type Response is not JSON serializable
```

This is what i am doing

```
from flask import jsonify, Response
from flask_restplus import Resource
    class MyUsage(Resource):
        def get(self):
        # Do something
        return "My Description" + jsonify(myObject), 200
```

I even tried sending the object like:

```
result = {'Desc': 'My Description',
          'Result': jsonify(myObject)}
return result, 200
```

and

```
return jsonify('Desc': 'My Description',
               'Result': myObject), 200
```

Everything failed with the same error.

Answer (score 2):

`jsonify` will not serialize an object. It is used to convert a dictionary to a valid JSON response (there may be some exceptions to this).

There are a few ways to handle this. My personal favorite is with the `marshmallow` library because you can use it to deserialize request data into an object while also validating the data and for serializing your objects into a dictionary. This way your objects are never instantiated in an invalid state.

Another way that may be easier but less scalable, is writing a `to_data` method for your object.

```
class Object():
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def to_data(self):
        return {
            'a': self.a,
            'b', self.b
        }
```

You can use this method to serialize your object.

```
myObject = Object(1,2)
data = myObject.to_data()
return jsonify(data), 200
```

Comment: Looks like there is something wrong with the snippet. Does it have to be like: data = Object(description,myObject) serialized_data = data.to_data() return jsonify(serialized_data), 200 ?

Comment: Yea you need to instantiate the object of course. I made an edit to show that. I figured that step was obvious so I left it out.

Answer (score 0):

just as @Kevin said,

> `jsonify` will not serialize an object. It is used to convert a
> dictionary to a valid JSON response (there may be some exceptions to
> this).

I will provide another solution.
I notice that `flask_restplus` was used in your code, actually flask_restplus will do jsonfy automatically. The following source code is from flask_rest

```
    def make_response(self, data, *args, **kwargs):
    '''
    Looks up the representation transformer for the requested media
    type, invoking the transformer to create a response object. This
    defaults to default_mediatype if no transformer is found for the
    requested mediatype. If default_mediatype is None, a 406 Not
    Acceptable response will be sent as per RFC 2616 section 14.1

    :param data: Python object containing response data to be transformed
    '''
    default_mediatype = kwargs.pop('fallback_mediatype', None) or self.default_mediatype
    mediatype = request.accept_mimetypes.best_match(
        self.representations,
        default=default_mediatype,
    )
    if mediatype is None:
        raise NotAcceptable()
    if mediatype in self.representations:
        resp = self.representations[mediatype](data, *args, **kwargs)
        resp.headers['Content-Type'] = mediatype
        return resp
    elif mediatype == 'text/plain':
        resp = original_flask_make_response(str(data), *args, **kwargs)
        resp.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        return resp
    else:
        raise InternalServerError()
```

and the mediatype of self.representations is `application/json`, which means when media type of request is `application/json`, response will use `representations['application/json']` function, to build up Response.

And that will call

```
def output_json(data, code, headers=None):
'''Makes a Flask response with a JSON encoded body'''

settings = current_app.config.get('RESTPLUS_JSON', {})

# If we're in debug mode, and the indent is not set, we set it to a
# reasonable value here.  Note that this won't override any existing value
# that was set.
if current_app.debug:
    settings.setdefault('indent', 4)

# always end the json dumps with a new line
# see https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/pull/1262
dumped = dumps(data, **settings) + "\n"

resp = make_response(dumped, code)
resp.headers.extend(headers or {})
return resp
```

With that said, you could setup `RESTPLUS_JSON` in your flask `app.config`

For exacmple, datetime is not a serializable object, therefore you could provide a convertor for that type as following code show.

First, you need to define a converter:

```
def datetime_json_converter(o):
if isinstance(o, datetime.datetime):
    return o.__str__()
```

Then, you just need to set `RESTPLUS_JSON` in your flask `app.config`

```
app.config['RESTPLUS_JSON'] = {'default': datetime_json_converter}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the best solution is to use marshalling.
First you need to write a model, explaining what attributes from the object you want to use and what will be type of each attribute.

```
from flask_restplus import Resource, fields

model = api.model('Model', {
    'name': fields.String,
    'address': fields.String,
    'date_updated': fields.DateTime(dt_format='rfc822'),
})
```

then you need to apply that on resource methods you want.

```
@api.route('/<id>')
class Todo(Resource):

    @api.marshal_with(model) <-- Here you refer the model you created above 
    def get(self, id):
        
        # find or prepare your object and just return that object
        return object
```